# How to access a remote OPC server programmatically?

Tags: client-server, remote-access, opc

I have downloaded & installed the OPCDA.NET client component evaluation & XMLDA.NET client component evaluation. It provides some C# samples for browsing the available OPC Server, connecting to the OPC server, & browsing the available items on the server.

I know the programmatic way in which we can access the local OPC server. It is provided in the sample C# applications. I have installed the OPC server on another machine (remote machine). I have done all the required setting related to the 'dcomcnfg' utility. I can access the remote OPC server from client machine by using the Test Client provided by the OPCDA.NET client component evaluation & XMLDA.NET client component evaluation. But I am unaware of how this can be done programmatically.

In the available C# samples I found no such programmatic part (coding) in which we can access the remote OPC server. Can you provide me the code through which I can browse the available remote machines in my network, available OPC server on each machine after selecting the specific machine name, connecting to the OPC server & browsing the available items on the server? Or can you provide me any link through which I can resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OpcServer.cs, I see an overloaded Connect() method which can receive a hostname or IP address:

```
public int Connect(string ComputerName, string SrvName)
```